# How to quickly understand the layout in various digital console

Tags: sound-design, sound, software, audio-interfaces, live-sound

Well i don't know if am asking this question on the right platform but anyways i can't help it so I'll still put it through. With the rapid growth in digital processing from various manufacturers especially in the area of digital console were two different audio mixer does not have the same layout, routing, gestures etc. This really tend to makes things a bit cumbersome for me because alot of the time am i might be called upon to render a quick service to a club house or church with a console am not familiar with, so i have to go through a quick snippets to find myself around it which is not cool for me. Therefore my concern is, are other engineers experiencing this challenges? Is there a better options to find your way around this different interfaces in digital console now, or in the future? If so what are they so i can keep up to speed?

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to be familiar with the industry standard equipment if you want to get jobs.
Most companies have training videos on their consoles.

Comment: Also, some manufacturers will allow you to download a simulator which you can run on your windows or osx box that shows you basically how the system works and can be configured.

Comment: The problem is, there's no such thing as "industry standard equipment" any more. Every company uses wildly different designs for their console UI, and even within manufacturers you get massive differences (Behringer X32 vs Wing, for instance). It's like the bad old days of personal computing before Mac OS and Windows provided standardized interfaces.